# what is the temperature rating for typical wire nuts?

Tags: electrical

What is the temperature rating for normal wire nuts, not specialized high-temp ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the manufacturer's specifications for the exact make an model in question, but many are rated for 105°C (221°F).

Answer (score 2):

The 2 main brands ideal and scotch lock (3M) the standard wire nuts are rated for 105c 221f. 
But there are high temp versions also available that are listed to 150c , 302f.  The standard 105c nuts are colored by size so they are easy to tell apart, the high temp ones are all the same color a dark black/ blueish gray color on the ones I have. 
FWIW , there are also high temp spade and ring/fork crimp connectors, most folks don't know this and do oven and heater repairs with the standard tin plated copper ones when the element heats the low temp connectors loosen up and sometimes the arcing blows the connector off, I have found this on several DIY repairs that I used the proper high temp connectors to make a proper repair. These connectors are rated at 900f. I hope the extra info is helpfull to someone that may be repairing a portable heater or oven, where I have found the wrong type of terminals used.